# Schengen visa delay from embassy

Tags: france, italy, spain, netherlands, norway

I applied for a Schengen visa 20 days ago. Usually, they  grant the visa within 15 days. I have traveled on time, came back on time after a 6-day holiday. I was granted a visa 3 times. But this time no reply. It's been 20 days already.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: @dda and Waqar, the use of capital letters for emphasis is considered "shouting", even more so than *italics* or **bold**. dda, I think your comment was too cryptic in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

Monday was December 25th, Christmas Day. All non-essential services and offices were closed in most of the Schengen zone. Many workers take leave a few days before Christmas and between Christmas and New Year, so even if offices are "open" they might be operating at a reduced capacity.

Visa will still be processed, but I'm not surprised if the decision takes a few days longer. (That goes for positive and negative answers.)